# Drag an animated object with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a fiddle here where a black box moves slowly across the screen. I also want to be able to drag the black box and move it into the pink box, but I can't figure it out. I was trying to use the code below but it kept breaking everything. I'm a newbie, so if you can help,  please give as much explanation as you can.  Thanks a lot!

**Update: Sorry, I initially had the wrong fiddle posted. This is correct now**

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/LeztD/1/

```
$(function() {
        $( "#draggable, #draggable-nonvalid" ).draggable();
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
            accept: "#draggable",
            activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this )
                    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                    .find( "p" )
                        .html( "Dropped!" );
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the animation when the drag starts:

http://jsfiddle.net/LeztD/2/

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    start: function() {
        $(this).stop();
    },
    stop: function(){
         cloudMove();   
    }
});
```

This code basically stops the animation when you start dragging and starts it back up when you release it.

You'll probably want to modify `cloudMove` to take into consideration the location of the box when the animation starts and adjust the duration.

Comment: In my implementation of it (www.instagirl.com), I'm dragging an image, but the html message is not appearing once it's dropped in, so I'm not sure if it's working. Also, do you know how to remove the image after it's dropped?  the white box on my site is supposed to be droppable

Comment: not a problem actually,  the html message shows up but have to be very accurate about where placed

Comment: As far as removing the image.  Within your `dropped` function, `ui.draggable` is the element which was dropped.  Simply do `ui.draggable.remove();`.